# Acces dynamically created controls from other method C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to acces my dynamically created `Textbox` through the click of a button.

```
private void assortiment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lastorder = "Select MAX(idorders) From orders";


    string query = "Select * From Product";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(lastorder, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    label1lblorderid.Text = orderid.ToString();
    var cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Image");
    int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;
    var y = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(data);

        //picture box creation
        var pbList = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pic" + i,
            Size = new Size(150, 150),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
        };

        //panel creation
        var tblPanelList = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            Name = "tblp" + i,
            Size = new Size(380, 150),
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, y),
            BackColor = Color.ForestGreen,
            GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddColumns,
            ColumnCount = 2
        };

        //other
        productid = Convert.ToInt32((ds.Tables["Image"]
                               .Rows[i]["idproduct"]).ToString());

        //Textbox: Aantal
        var tbAantal = new TextBox { Size = new Size(107, 20), 
                                         Name = "tbaantal" + productid};

        //label productid
        var lblproductid = new Label();
        lblproductid.Text = productid.ToString();

        //Button: Bestellen
        var btnBestel = new Button();
        btnBestel.Name = "bestel" + productid;
        btnBestel.Text = "Bestellen";
        btnBestel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
        btnBestel.Click += btnBestel_Click;

        //Voeg controls toe
        this.panel.Controls.Add(pbList);
        this.Controls.Add(tblPanelList);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(naam);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(omschrijving);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(lblAantal);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(tbAantal);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(btnBestel,1,10);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(lblproductid);
        y = y + 156;
    }        
}

void btnBestel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm frm_1 = new MainForm();

    var button = sender as Button;
    string btnname = button.Name.ToString();
    //btnname.Remove(1, 6);
    int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(label1lblorderid.Text);
    Control tbAantalControl = FindControl("tbAantal" + btnname.Remove(0, 6));
    int aantal = Convert.ToInt32(tbAantalControl.Text);
    //MessageBox.Show(btnname.Remove(0,6));
    string query = "Insert Into orderproduct(idorder, idproduct, aantal) 
                     Values('" + orderid + "'" + productid +
                     "'" + aantal + "')";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As you can see, I have already tried to access the `Textbox` by a `FindControl()`, But this didn't work. I want the `Textbox` that has the same last value as the clicked `TextBox`, I'm trying to do this by cutting the string and paste that in a variable.

Please help.

Comment: are you aware that you are creating the `TextBox`es with name `tbaantal...` but are searching for `tbAantal...`?

Comment: `FindControl` is your method? Can you show the code?

Comment: try `tblPanelList.FindControl`, you are adding `Textbox` to `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot the tblPanelList is also dynamically created so its actually the same issue as my question, i dont know how to acces it.

Comment: @olydis, Still won't work :(, Very good btw, i felt really dumb when you said that haha :)

Comment: @JumpingJack you need recursive find method. If you give valid control names.

Comment: @HassanNisar please explain, I've never heard of recursive findmethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are searching for `TextBox`es with different names than you create them with (`tbAantal...` vs. `tbaantal...`). Together with a recursive `Find` method that *would* work.

Neither is that good practice nor is it fast.

---

**Better**

Rather than searching for controls by name each time you create them you should implement something that *directly* let's you retrieve the controls (via some identifier or similar, in your case: via `productid`).

For example:

Declare a `Dictionary<int, TextBox> textBoxes` as a local variable. In your loop, add `textBoxes.Add(productid, tbAantal);` right after your definition of `tbAantal`.

In `btnBestel_Click` you can then use this mapping to retrieve the correct `TextBox` via `textBoxes[productid]`.
I am aware that you don't really have the `productid` defined in that context.

Instead of using `btnname.Remove(0, 6)`, you should use the `Buttons`'s `Tag` property and store the `productid` as extra metadata:

Back in your loop add `btnBestel.Tag = productid;` at the appropriate position. In `btnBestel_Click` you can then write `textBoxes[(int)button.Tag]`.

**Overall code in that case**

```
Dictionary<int, TextBox> textBoxes = new Dictionary<int,TextBox>();

private void assortiment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lastorder = "Select MAX(idorders) From orders";


    string query = "Select * From Product";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(lastorder, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    label1lblorderid.Text = orderid.ToString();
    var cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Image");
    int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;
    var y = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(data);

        //picture box creation
        var pbList = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pic" + i,
            Size = new Size(150, 150),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
        };

        //panel creation
        var tblPanelList = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            Name = "tblp" + i,
            Size = new Size(380, 150),
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, y),
            BackColor = Color.ForestGreen,
            GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddColumns,
            ColumnCount = 2
        };

        //other
        productid = Convert.ToInt32((ds.Tables["Image"]
                                .Rows[i]["idproduct"]).ToString());

        //Textbox: Aantal
        var tbAantal = new TextBox { Size = new Size(107, 20), 
                                            Name = "tbaantal" + productid};
        textBoxes.Add(productid, tbAantal);

        //label productid
        var lblproductid = new Label();
        lblproductid.Text = productid.ToString();

        //Button: Bestellen
        var btnBestel = new Button();
        btnBestel.Name = "bestel" + productid;
        btnBestel.Text = "Bestellen";
        btnBestel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
        btnBestel.Click += btnBestel_Click;
        btnBestel.Tag = productid;

        //Voeg controls toe
        this.panel.Controls.Add(pbList);
        this.Controls.Add(tblPanelList);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(naam);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(omschrijving);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(lblAantal);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(tbAantal);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(btnBestel,1,10);
        tblPanelList.Controls.Add(lblproductid);
        y = y + 156;
    }        
}

void btnBestel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm frm_1 = new MainForm();

    var button = sender as Button;
    int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(label1lblorderid.Text);
    Control tbAantalControl = textBoxes[(int)button.Tag];
    int aantal = Convert.ToInt32(tbAantalControl.Text);
    string query = "Insert Into orderproduct(idorder, idproduct, aantal) 
                        Values('" + orderid + "'" + productid +
                        "'" + aantal + "')";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I'm implementing this code but, i'm getting a NullReferenceException @     textBoxes.Add(productid, tbAantal); What should i do?

Comment: then you didn't initialize `textBoxes`, it is still `null` in that line ;-)

Comment: ooh, my screen just refreshed, please let me review your new answer

Comment: hehe yes then you most probably forgot the `textBoxes = new Dictionary<int,TextBox>()` :-)

Comment: Yes I thought of that 5 seconds after I posted that comment *FacePalm()*

Comment: And that's exactly what I forgot haha :$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are giving valid control name for search. For checking you should apply  break point on the line, to see if you are getting valid control name.

For searching your required control by name you should look into each parent control recursively. `FindControl` method can be used for the purpose.

Change this:

```
Control tbAantalControl = FindControl("tbAantal" + btnname.Remove(0, 6));
```

With this:

```
Control tbAantalControl = FindControl(this.Controls, "tbAantal" + btnname.Remove(0, 6));
```

Method that recursive find your required:

```
 private Control FindControl(Control.ControlCollection controlCollection, string name)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
        {
            if (control.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
            {
                return control;
            }

            if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                Control result = FindControl(control.Controls, name);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why you can't just make `tbAantal` a form level variable and then reference that in the `btnBestel_Click` method?

```
var tbAantal = null;

private void assortiment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lastorder = "Select MAX(idorders) From orders";


        string query = "Select * From Product";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(lastorder, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        label1lblorderid.Text = orderid.ToString();
        var cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Image");
        int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;
        var y = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data);

            //picture box creation
            var pbList = new PictureBox
            {
                Name = "pic" + i,
                Size = new Size(150, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
            };

            //panel creation
            var tblPanelList = new TableLayoutPanel
            {
                Name = "tblp" + i,
                Size = new Size(380, 150),
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(219, y),
                BackColor = Color.ForestGreen,
                GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddColumns,
                ColumnCount = 2

            };

            //other
            productid = Convert.ToInt32((ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["idproduct"]).ToString());

            //Textbox: Aantal
            tbAantal = new TextBox { Size = new Size(107, 20), Name = "tbaantal" + productid};


            //label productid
            var lblproductid = new Label();
             lblproductid.Text = productid.ToString();


             //Button: Bestellen
             var btnBestel = new Button();
             btnBestel.Name = "bestel" + productid;
             btnBestel.Text = "Bestellen";
             btnBestel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
             btnBestel.Click += btnBestel_Click;

            //Voeg controls toe
            this.panel.Controls.Add(pbList);
            this.Controls.Add(tblPanelList);
            tblPanelList.Controls.Add(naam);
            tblPanelList.Controls.Add(omschrijving);
            tblPanelList.Controls.Add(lblAantal);
            tblPanelList.Controls.Add(tbAantal);
            tblPanelList.Controls.Add(btnBestel,1,10);
            tblPanelList.Controls.Add(lblproductid);


            y = y + 156;
        }

    }

    void btnBestel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm frm_1 = new MainForm();

        var button = sender as Button;
        string btnname = button.Name.ToString();
        //btnname.Remove(1, 6);
        int orderid = Convert.ToInt32(label1lblorderid.Text);
        int aantal = Convert.ToInt32(tbAantal.Text);
        //MessageBox.Show(btnname.Remove(0,6));
        string query = "Insert Into orderproduct(idorder, idproduct, aantal) Values('" + orderid + "'" + productid +
                       "'" + aantal + "')";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Could be an option, but I still need to access the tbAantal where the last characters of the string ar the same as that of (button)Sender

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had several buttons.  You could define tbAantal as type TextBox[] and then store each TextBox created in the array. Then you could loop through them checking the last characters of each one